# How to include folders when opening HTML file in-browser?

Tags: html, css, browser

I am using the latest updated version of Chrome.

I am trying out external CSS and images for the first time, the heirarchy works like this:

```
>parent folder
 -index.html (html file uploaded)
 >images
  -file1.jpeg 
  -file2.jpeg
 >css
  -styles.css (css file)
```

When I go to test what I wrote, it's only showing the index.html folder with plain HTML despite using the proper `link href="css/styles.css"` and `img src="images/file1.jpeg"` tags. How do I include these external folders when testing website work?

Here is the head section of the index page

```
 <head>
 <title>West Coast Emirates</title>
 <meta name ="description" content = "A look at Arsenal's 12/13 season in the   Barclay's Premier League"/>
 <link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 </head>
```

I am opening the html file in a browser, no servers or anything just a word processor and chrome

Comment: It would be really helpful if you pasted the head section of your index.html. You should also use the developer-tools in chrome to see if there are any errors in the console.

Comment: I'm also a little curious about what you have done: Have you uploaded your page to a site but not the folders? Or have you opened your html file in a browser and the images doesn't show up?

Comment: We definitely need more information.  It's probably a very straightforward fix to your problem, but without more context we can't do much.

Comment: I am curious if you should be using a link that reads from the root of your site, instead of 'link href="css/styles.css"' (which reads from the directory you are in) use 'link href="/css/styles.css"' which reads from the base of your site.

Comment: Are you actually deploying the css files to the server? Can you browse to the styles.css file and get content?

Comment: I'm noticing you say 'html file uploaded' for the html.  Is this the same for the css and image files? Make sure you check all filenames and locations are correct one more time and tell us if anything seems amiss.

Comment: @Vegar opened the html file in a browser and the images don't show up

Comment: @DrCord I don't have a website, I'm justing using ctrl+O to open an .html file

Comment: @Tim No server, just opening them in a browser

Comment: From what you're describing, this looks like a pathing issue. Are you sure your images and css folders are under your parent folder and the html file is under the parent folder? What browser are you using? Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: but even if you are opening the base file, it references other files. The path to those other files may be incorrect, depending on your folder structure. Without more information, we probably won't be able to help you. Do you mean that all of the files are located only on your computer and you are just loading a file with ctrl-O. That may be a problem for you, web pages need to reside on some type of server to work correctly. you should look into WAMP - http://www.wampserver.com/en/, it lets you run a webserver on your local computer.

Comment: Again I will suggest that you check out the console to see if Chrome is giving you some hints. On a mac its Command+Alt+i, on windows I think maybe its Control+Shift+i. If the index.html isn't too large, you could past the rest of it too. Would make it much easier to see whats going on. If it's large, you could put it in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) or something.

Comment: @DrCord Yes, all the files are on my computer and I'm just loading a file with crtl-O. Sorry I just didn't know that I needed a server to do what I'm looking for. I'm looking at the Wampserver website, but it looks like I need knowledge of PHP to use it? If so I think I'm best off just using internal CSS for what I need

Comment: wamp will let you serve php pages, but it can also serve plain html pages. In your case, you shouldn't need any server at all. all browsers are able to show local html pages with images and css. Have you tried out the development tools inside of chrome? Could you paste the rest of your index.html? Or have you sorted the issue out? Should the question just be closed, abandoned or deleted?